# javascript timezone weirdness: new Date() creating dates in different timezones

Tags: javascript, date

I have some javascript that is acting weird. I create two dates, but they are randomly in different timezones which is messing me up when calculating the difference between the two. I am in the EST timezone, but for some reason the first date get created as a EDT date.

Basically my question is ***why does this javascript produce the output that it does***?

```
var xstartTime = new Date(startYear, StartMonth, StartDay, StartHour, StartMinute, 0, 0);
var xendTime = new Date(EndYear, EndMonth, EndDay, EndHour, EndMinute, 0, 0);
console.log("StartMinute" + StartMinute + "StartHour" + StartHour + "StartDay" + StartDay + "StartMonth" + StartMonth + "startYear" + startYear);
console.log(xstartTime);
console.log("EndMinute" + EndMinute + "EndHour" + EndHour + "EndDay" + EndDay + "EndMonth" + EndMonth + "EndYear" + EndYear);
console.log(xendTime);
```

StartMinute0StartHour0StartDay3StartMonth10startYear2013

Sun Nov 3 00:00:00 EDT 2013

EndMinute59EndHour23EndDay3EndMonth10EndYear2013

Sun Nov 3 23:59:00 EST 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a JavaScript problem, it's related to timezones. Taken from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) Wikipedia article:

> During the first Sunday in November, at 2:00 a.m. EDT, clocks are
>   moved back to 1:00 a.m. EST, thus "duplicating" one hour.

Your date is coincidentally the first Sunday of November 2013. `xstartTime` is 00:00 EDT but since `xendTime` is after 1:00 am, its timezone is EST.